# angular-ui bootstrap second modal will trigger white ghost block in Chrome

Tags: angular-ui-bootstrap

When I try to open the second modal from the first modal, there will show up white ghost block area. Looks like there is an issue to mask the first modal correctly. Here is the demo:

```
 demo link:::  http://plnkr.co/edit/5DZT2QDnASGhJXoRPqzs?p=preview
```

open the demo with Chrome, click 'first modal' and 'second modal', then resize the result window the issue will show up. in IE it has no issue at all.

Any solution?

Comment: I have an exactly the same problem with Chrome. I am using angular 2.4  with custom bootstrap 4 theme. If you disable hardware acceleration problem disappear but this is not real solution.